# Getting Started with Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am new to game development. I had recently worked with Unity 3D but its not free so I switched over to Unreal Engine. Documentation on Epic Games's website is not in detail and hard to understand for new game developers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was new to Unreal Engine, I looked into the following video playlist. 
Have a look. It is collection of 208 Videos.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZlv_N0_O1gaCL2XjKluO7N2Pmmw9pvhE

Comment: Yes, definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to check out this guy's channel on YouTube: [TeslaDev](https://www.youtube.com/user/TeslaUE4/playlists)

There are great tutorials there.